# Notification not receive

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications, facebook-php-sdk

i've made a simple facebook App!

The App send notification with server: the settings are like this:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; 

$facebook = new \Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'APP_ID',
  'app_secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
]);


$facebook->post('/FB_USER_ID/notifications', array('href' => '#', 'template' => "Message to Share"), 'APP_TOKEN');
```

Always the message are: Success: True. but some user (example me, and other my friends) not receive a notification.. my profile allow to receive notification by that app.. and all facebook settings are right.

Why i not receive a notification and a lot of other user works fine?

Thank You

Comment: Facebook decide who to show the notification for.

Comment: Ah ok! and there is not any solution to get all notifications? i've checked all privacy and notify settings.. but nothing works :(

Comment: No there is no way